# How to play a quartz composer movie with a custom plugin in Quicktime player

Tags: quartz-composer

I have an application where I need to make a Quartz movie using Quartz Composer and a custom plugin and have it run in a 3rd party application which is capable of playing Quartz movies.

As a first step I successfully developed my custom plug in using Xcode and 'built' a composition in Quartz Composer.  I got this all running in Quartz Composer and this works totally fine in the viewer inside Quartz Composer.

Subsequently I tried to play it in the 3rd party application and it would not play, other parts of the movie played but my plugin simply did not function.  I then tried QuickTime player and on one machine it behaved exactly the same - movie played but my plugin didn't function.  On another machine I get the error "Quicktime player quit unexpectedly while using the "My Plugin Name" plug-in.

After this I was a little baffled and I read the forums and I came across the notion of Safe and Unsafe patches.  I am wondering if this is why my patch doesn't work in applications other than Quartz composer.

If I enable the "Indicate Unsafe Patches" menu item then it shows an unlocked padlock icon on plug in presumably indicating it is in fact Unsafe.

Some questions:

Am I on the right track, is it not playing my custom plugin because it is considered unsafe?
How can I tell 'an application' or the system that it is safe?
What is the correct way to achieve what I am wanting to do?
Any other ideas, useful information welcome.

Thank you,
Kind Regards,
Callum.

Answer (score 1):

[KinemeCore](http://kineme.net/KinemeCore)'s "Unsafe Mode" can be used to bypass safe mode for specified combinations of patches and applications.

From http://kineme.net/wiki/SafeMode:

> After installing KinemeCore, launch Quartz Composer, click on the "K" menu and select Preferences, then configure Unsafe Mode to allow whichever QC Patches you need to use in whichever applications.